# Why TCategoryPanel.controls[i].className always "TCategoryPanelSurface?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

On a form I put down 1 x `TCategoryPanelGroup` object and added 3 `TCategoryPanel` to it. In a routine, I need to go through each of `TCategoryPanel` and through each object onto those panel to produce an output.

So, here is the code ... why into the second FOR instead of giving me classname of each component (i.e. `TButton`, `TLabel`, etc) it gives out a `TCategoryPanelSurface`?

Short question: How can I access each controls from each TCategoryPanel?

---

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    var i,i2 : integer;

    begin
      for i := 0 to CategoryPanelGroup1.ControlCount-1 do
      begin
        showMessage((CategoryPanelGroup1.Controls[i] as TCategoryPanel).caption ) ;

        for i2 := 0 to (CategoryPanelGroup1.Controls[i] as TCategoryPanel).ControlCount-1 do
        begin

          showMessage((CategoryPanelGroup1.Controls[i] as TCategoryPanel).Controls[i2].ClassName);
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looping through the Group's underlying `TWinControl.Controls[]` list when you should be looping through its `TCategoryPanelGroup.Panels` list instead.

As for why you are seeing a `TCategoryPanelSurface` appear, `TCategoryPanel` creates that object as a direct child of itself in its constructor.  Any control you place into the Panel afterwards is actually a child of that `TCategoryPanelSurface` object, not a child of the `TCategoryPanel` itself.  That is why your looping never sees those controls.

Unfortunately, `TCategoryPanel` does not expose direct access to its `TCategoryPanelSurface` object.  So, in order to loop through its children, you have to first be able to access it.  There are two possible ways to do that:

1)

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
  panel: TCategoryPanel;
  surface: TCategoryPanelSurface;
begin
  for i := 0 to CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels.Count-1 do
  begin
    panel := TCategoryPanel(CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels[i]);
    ShowMessage(panel.Caption);
    surface := panel.Controls[0] as TCategoryPanelSurface;
    for j := 0 to surface.ControlCount-1 do
    begin
      ShowMessage(surface.Controls[j].ClassName);
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

2)

```
type
  TCategoryPanelAccess = class(TCategoryPanelAccess)
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
  panel: TCategoryPanel;
  surface: TCategoryPanelSurface;
begin
  for i := 0 to CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels.Count-1 do
  begin
    panel := TCategoryPanel(CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels[i]);
    ShowMessage(panel.Caption);
    surface := TCategoryPanelAccess(panel).FPanelSurface;
    for j := 0 to surface.ControlCount-1 do
    begin
      ShowMessage(surface.Controls[j].ClassName);
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: I used your solution 1) but with a little fix into your code.

line : panel := CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels[i] as TCategoryPanel;

becomes : panel := CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels[i];


Thanks again, work's fine !

Comment: The Panels property is a TList, which contains untyped Pointer values.  That is why I was type-casting those pointers when accessing them.

Comment: I also got a compile error compiling solution 1 on XE4 (operator not applicable to this operand type) on the line `panel := CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels[i] as TCategoryPanel;` just as Jaune did, but taking out the typecast and changing it to `panel := CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels[i];` as in his comment it compiled fine.